# Why Observer does not emit events when the observed values becomes nil?

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift

I'm trying to observe my variable user. When I set a new value to it that is not nil my drive(onNext) is called, but when I set the user variable as nil the drive(onNext) is not called. It's suppose to happen? What's the explanation for that?

```
  static var userObservable: Observable<User?> = {
        Observable<User?>.create() { observer in
            observer.onNext(UserDefaults.user)

            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }()

UserDefaults.userObservable
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: nil)
            .drive(onNext: {[weak self] user in
                print(user) // when UserDefaults.user receives a new value that is not nil this line of code is called. But when that value is nil it's not called.
            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have passed a closure into Observable.create. That closure is called once for every subscribe (drive.) That closure emits the current value of `UserDefaults.user` and nothing else. The reason your drive is not called again is because the closure you passed to the create function is no longer executing.

You don't tell us what `UserDefaults.user` is, but if the idea is to track the value of a stored user default, you do that with the observe function. Like:

```
let savedString = UserDefaults.standard.rx.observe(String.self, "myString")
```